# Get Environment Type in Swift5

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to ios development I am not sure how to get the environment type in ios.

I have 3 environments in my application dev, stage and prod. My question is how to get the selected environment or how to get the type of environment type using swift5.

for ex: if I created a build using dev config then the environment will be dev.

How we can achieve this programmatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode build configuration files, more commonly known by their xcconfig file extension, allow build settings for your app to be declared and managed without Xcode

add a new file and select the Configuration Settings File name *example: dev.xcconfig, prod.xcconfig, ..*

Add flag for for each *.xcconfig file *-DDEV, -DPROD*

```
OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS = $(inherited) -DDEV
```

In code usage:

```
#if DEV
// dev environment
#elseif PROD
// prod environment
#endif
```

Once you’ve created an xcconfig file, you can assign it to one or more build configurations for its associated targets.

Comment: It's probably important to mention that you can also set up that kind of configuration without using _xcconfig_ files.

Comment: Hi, I already did this. But My question is how to get the build type programmatically. There is one API in which I have to send the build type. How I can achieve that.

Comment: add value in .xcconfig `MY_BUILD_TYPE = DEV`
set in Info.plist key
`   <key>MY_BUILD_TYPE</key>
    <string>$(MY_BUILD_TYPE)</string>`

After read value
    `guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist"),
        let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: AnyObject],
        let buildType = dict["MY_BUILD_TYPE"] as? String else {
            return
    }
    print(buildType)`